# Need assistance with the Android Manifest XML File within my Launcher App

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter, launcher

Hoping someone can point out my failure here. Ive developed a custom launcher app which I want to replace the home screen. I also want the activity accessible via a custom URL "myapp://launcher.android.com."

I'd love to explain why, but to cut a long story short, the Android Gods demanded that I consolidate two activities (each working fine) into a single Activity.

Can someone check over my manifest file to point out any errors or fields I need to fix? Or even a superior alternative?

```
<activity
android:name=".KioskLauncher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" >
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
     <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="kiosk.androiddev.com" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />    
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: "Hoping someone can point out my failure here" -- that will be difficult, as you have not indicated what your symptoms are. What is the actual "failure" that you refer to?

Comment: Sorry that would help.. the problem with the attached manifest file is that the prompt to select my app as the default home launcher doesnt appear  when pressing the home button. Usually when an app that has a launcher is installed, the system detects it and asks which one you want to use as your default launcher.

Comment: Hmmm... that certainly looks like it should work. Are you sure you didn't, somewhere along the line, have the chooser and select "always", to tell Android to bypass the chooser in the future? You might try fully uninstalling and reinstalling the app. Also, FYI, unless your app is going to be preinstalled on production hardware, `Theme.DeviceDefault` as a base is an unusual choice.

Comment: yes im sure.. ive tried resetting the default launcher myself and even forcing my app as the default launcher through the settings but my app doesnt appear there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an extra attribute to be added to the activity tag.
Try adding this to the activity tag:

android:launchMode="singleTask"

Comment: Thanks for that. Still not quite there yet, though it has made a slight difference. I now get prompted for default launcher but can't see my app listed.

Comment: Try adding this to the FIRST <intent-filter>::
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

Comment: I actually tried the DEFAULT category with no luck before but using it with the launchmode="singleTask" seems to have done the trick. Theres only one more hurdle though.. I cant get the second intent filter to trigger the activity. So when clicking on a hyperlink within the browser to myapp://kiosk.androiddev.com should launch my activity. I had this all working with separate activities so its gotta be a setting in the manifest.

Comment: Woohooo got it all working!! Been stumped on this for days.. Ill know next time to consult the stackoverflow community sooner. Thanks for the speedy replies guys. FYI, The 2nd part of my last comment regarding the intent filter was due to my own error.

Comment: I've got one more challenge I can't seem to overcome. I can't seem to access the second Intent Filter even though I am entering my app via the browser intent. The app stays running in the background so it seems to hold onto all the activity properties from the first launch. Given that I can't kill my app because its the default launcher, do I have any choices here?